# Echarts: Incorrect Area Style in Timeseries Stacked Area Line Chart with missing value

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization, echarts, timeserieschart

I'm experiencing an issue with Echarts where the area style is not being correctly applied in a timeseries chart when there are missing values. This problem manifests as unexpected white spaces appearing between two area styles.

Here's a simplified example of the issue I'm facing: [EXAMPLE](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-rich-text&edit=1&reset=1&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULTsBEAjAhgMYDWA5gE7ACu0AJgMLAA2w52AXDmOftAM4h85AKbQw2ADTosOJsNKjaHZNJlZsfABbAA7su5VhUjGszYwATxDDlGwpSZNJq09lYRR4ztgBuw8pCE-E7GMgC-oeoUEEqcqCauhDBg-BDQADL4uMJOnAZGLrARhebAzJAgyvGmZlq6-uSGka7cEKQKbN74AB4QfM4JRc043QCCvf1xhTLmVjbekAC2NsPFg9gW431V0-qW1rY-wYYD4cOlzLjA3TuDM-6eh_6Bwac1Gtp6eY0Fg2szfH8HkmsAA2rtMNUajNoPhlrZAeRgbAAIxvaFmWj4FLKcF3DGYUEogDsAAYAJyk0kAZgArAAWFFU0kSWDUgC6wwJhJJFKpdPpACZmaziZyIRiiWTKTSGdSRajxfiCVK-bL6fSFeSldy1KqZQLaQrBTrdVh9fyGQA2BUADlNZrBvINDLJVNZ9IdZoA9N6ndLLfTbQqrV7db7_WqBTKWajSWHuRGLbKjQraQmCUnnZbaUz3bAxVzE37k3TacL8xyi5mS9mU_L86HqxiswGU5r8ybm9DS7S-3aMzVBzN9vNZGkVhKAYsymBNA0mlP1HwUiRbAAVYApEJLsxCYT4ADKljkVX-xZwdR0h4siyuuVgADNgoDu1g-Lf74eIAAvYTsYk3zMYRFhATR8D4bYpmVDFsEfYBCCoEENCBYR-l3IYMOwJgJ2PCxT2gx0zB0GI52UFEADpaQwsIJXPUwoQJbBYXhbxEWRQV0VgrEcU4PEiMjF1GQVKsMJkXshQVQsxPNOsBQbWMUWHGoJI7WNtSAvU5IZVNYy7GSeTbAUbXze1NPE7T6TdWNPXM2SjIZYNG2U0wJJjVkmRcrSHN02N0zswyoz7PNY2kmCe208sRK8iyfIU1kmwMwSczU1l9PClTIt01kzJkrzZgObwcOgScMtqGct3nb5FzKy9V2IDct1eTTsH3I8TzHJB6JbP0Pl0G872YZRnyYV8MI_QamG_P8AJakCwIgqCVFqmZ4MQ5D2LQ7AaJa4rhDwgjloE7ASNoMjOEo6jatomDupkRjYJYscUKRNC2S46FsB4_BcSSiSQtZUSVvsoLJPzMKBIk-LFQC5L1VS2ANL-yzstgdLIcskzY1y4HAqE6yPRirBW1BpzY0S3HYBJoT3LjInMGpnNmT8-mqdrHyAYLVnGZTCtYyBjG4pDVnewZY0Raygc7Py0dbD2j73j4CrztgfIWpXIgGu8TdtwV1w2oOzq7pqCM-uvT8hs4Eaxtqiav1_f9AKw-bwMgkEHt1OCEKQhFUPQ67dtwjrbmO06Vcumi6JkQp2XQMIgA)

i have explored different chart configuration but not able to solve problem.

Comment: You could replace the missing values with 0?

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasMertens, it works but i have 50k to 1lakh data point with 250 series. so, i want to avoid loop. Also, we can use `null` which removes conflict between actual value `0` and `undefined`